# angularjs routing,am being mixed up with the real path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

am new to angularJS routing. am folowing a simple tutorial on routing but no +ve results
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>angularJS routing</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/foundation.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="viewApp">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ng-view.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ng-view.js**

```
var app = angular.module('viewApp', []);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('http://localhost/eclipse_PHP_Workspace/AngularJS/', {
    templateUrl : "ng-view-template.html",
    controller : "viewCtrl"
});
});

app.controller('viewCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.model = {
    message : "Helo ng-view !"
}
})
```

in the ng-view file above(`$routeProvider.when('http://localhost/eclipse_PHP_Workspace/AngularJS/',`), what does the path here realy mean .is it the application root folder or the server route folder coz all the tutorials am seeing even for john linquist he is using the server root folder.and is my path correct coz my angularJS app is in **http://localhost/eclipse_PHP_Workspace/AngularJS/**

Answer (score 0):

`$routeProvider.when` paths refer to the client-side route only. So this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', ...
```

would be equal to:

```
http://localhost/eclipse_PHP_Workspace/AngularJS/#/
```

Anything after the `#` will be the angular app's "route". Anything before the `#` is where the app lives on the server, which should never change in a single-page app.

This gets trickier if using html5mode, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: has anyone tried to use the **angular-route.min.js** offline fie coz with me itst giving alot of errors **uncaught exception errors and undefined route** and makes my app not function well but when I use the **cdn** files, the app works.anyone with simiar issue ?

Comment: this is the file I just found working offline **[https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/blob/master/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js]** bt the one from**[https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js]** does not work offline